# Wanting to convert cm^3 to L in python

Tags: python

I want to write a function that when I input the dimensions of a truncated cone (a cup) and an amount of liquid in litres returns how many of these cups can be filled up with the amount of liquid.I understand that 1L = 1000 cm^3 but I do not understand how I would incorporate it into my code to return the outcome I expect

```
def number_of_cups(bottom_radius, top_radius, height, litres_of_liquid):
    volume = math.pi / 3 * height * (bottom_radius**2 + top_radius * bottom_radius +  top_radius**2)


    return int(filled_cup)
```

This is as far as I have got, I know I am close but I don't understand how to word my conversion,

Comment: So is `volume` in terms of `cm^3`?

Comment: `1000*litres_of_liquid/volume`? I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean.

Comment: You are returning `filled_cup` which does not exist in your function

Comment: Is this what you want? `filled_cup = volume / litres_of_liquid`

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the unit in which bottom_radius, top_radius and height are given. If we assume that those length are given in cm then

```
def number_of_cups(bottom_radius, top_radius, height, litres_of_liquid):
    volume = math.pi / 3 * height * (bottom_radius**2 + top_radius * bottom_radius +  top_radius**2)
    return int( litres_of_liquid * 1000 / volume )
```

`litres_of_liquid * 1000` is litres converted to cm^3. The `int()` could be replaced by `math.floor()` in case the number of completely full cups is intended, `math.ceil()` will give the number of full or partially filled cups.

Finally, there is a nice package [magnitude](http://juanreyero.com/open/magnitude/) which encapsulates a physical quantity. You could use this package in case the user wants to specify different length units.

The Formula stated by the OP is correct.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just want to point out, your volume calculation seems wrong.

```
def number_of_cups(bottom_radius, top_radius, height, litres_of_liquid):  
    volume = 4 * math.pi * height * (bottom_radius**2 + top_radius**2)/2  
    filled_cup = 1000 * litres_of_liquid / volume  
    return int(filled_cup)
```

And in case you did't know, division is different in Python2 and Python3.

**Python 2**

```
>>> 1/2
0
```

**Python 3**

```
>>> 1/2
0.5
>>> 1//2
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my own anwer to the pile:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import math

# nothing about units here , but let's say it's cm
def cup_vol(b_rad=3, t_rad=4, h=5):  
    vol = math.pi/3 * (b_rad**2 + t_rad + b_rad + t_rad**2) * h
    return vol

def n_cups(liquid_amount, whole_cups=True):  # nothing about units here

    # liquid amount is Liter then first convert it to CM^3
    liquid_amount = liquid_amount*1000
    # this yields an int
    if whole_cups:
        return int(liquid_amount/cup_vol())
    # else, return a real number with fraction
    return liquid_amount/cup_vol() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "4L fill %f cups" % n_cups(4)
    print "4L fill %f cups (real)" % n_cups(4, whole_cups=False)
```

Running the above script yields:

```
4L fill 23.000000 cups
4L fill 23.873241 cups (real)
```